# Undefined reference to `ssFxpSetU​32BitRegio​nCompliant​' and `ssRegiste​rDataTypeF​xpBinaryPo​int'

Tags: matlab, compilation, simulink, mex

I am trying to compile a MEX file from a set of C source code files from our project. In the output specification function of the S function, I have defined 64 bit output parameter.
I had created a legacy code C file which acts as a wrapper to the source code files and tried compiling it along with other source code files with the command mex src1.c src2.c, ..... etc..,
On compiling the mex file, I get Undefined reference to `ssFxpSetU32BitRegionCompliant' and Undefined reference to`   ssRegisterDataTypeFxpBinaryPoint' errors.
I had inspected the legacy code generated C file and it already has the fixedpoint.h included which has the function definition for `ssFxpSetU32BitRegionCompliant' and` ssRegisterDataTypeFxpBinaryPoint'.
It is strange that there is error eventhough the fixedpoint.h file is included. I am using R2019b version.
Thanks

PS: I had also added fixedpoint.c file into the S function C file, But I still get the same error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How to solve the two errors?